# Group by sum with filter over grouped by total

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have df as below as:

```
State | x_date    |  y_date    | z_date   | amount | date_status
NY   2019-10-24      NaN         NaN       $400      2019-05-01
NJ   2019-07-24   2019-10-24 2019-10-20     $0       2019-05-01
CA      NaN       2019-01-24     NaN       $320      2019-05-01
WA      NaN          NaN         NaN       $10       2019-05-01
WA    2018-07-10     NaN         NaN       $100      2019-05-01
WA    2018-09-10     NaN     2019-10-10    $30       2019-05-01
```

How can I group by State column and get the sum of the amount column / sum of the amount of all the rows in that states groupings?

The numerator has to be the grouped the state columns sum of amount column **only if ANY of the dates in ***x_date, y_date or z_date*** are later than or after the date in the ***date_status*** column**

expected output:

```
State | pct 
NY      1
NJ      0
CA      0
WA     .21
```

where WA is (30/140)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward:

```
filtered_df = df[
    (df['x_date'] >= df['date_status']) 
    | (df['y_date'] >= df['date_status'])
    | (df['z_date'] >= df['date_status'])
]
result = (
    filtered_df.groupby('State').amount.sum()
    / df.groupby('State').amount.sum()
).fillna(0)
```

Result:

```
State
CA    0.000000
NJ    0.000000
NY    1.000000
WA    0.214286
Name: amount, dtype: float64
```